# Where are the magic bushes?

Tags: dota-2

In both jungles I heard there are special places between the trees that you can put your ward in order to block the neutral camps, and the ward is placed in a place where is difficult to access without skills or items that cut trees. These spots are known as magic bushes as far as I remember.

Can anyone point where are these spots? Pictures are desired, but not needed.

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/77757/how-do-i-ward-properly-in-dota-2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Credit to [this reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/1kbkke/jungle_camp_spawn_boxes/)

Beware : This visual guide is dated from before the small and medium camps were inversed, however, the spawn boxes are still the same. Placing a ward in the white areas block the camp.

- Red dots indicate the hidden wards that block the camp and require to cut down a tree to be found.
- Blue dots indicate wards that block the camp and provide a view of the rune as well
- The white text gives visual tips to remember the limit of those area in game
- **The magic bush** is indicated aswell (There is only 1 magic bush on the radiant side that block the hard camp and the small pull camp)

### Radiant side

[image]

### Dire side

[image]

### Ancient

[image]